# How to draw coordinate system on JPanel?

Tags: java, panel, paint, axis

I want to draw coordinate system on `JPanel`. Axes are drawing but not on panel.

To draw a line I use:

```java
public class Panel_rysowanie extends JPanel {
    public void Rysuj_uklad(int wysokosc, int szerokosc, Graphics grx) {
        grx.drawLine(wysokosc / 2, 0, wysokosc / 2, szerokosc);
        grx.drawLine(0, szerokosc / 2, wysokosc, szerokosc / 2);
    }
}
```

And I want to start drawing after button click.

Button code:

```java
Panel_rysowanie rysowanie_na_panelu = new Panel_rysowanie();
Rozwiazanie_rownania_obliczenia oblicz_rownanie = new Rozwiazanie_rownania_obliczenia();
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (RB_rownanie_kwadratowe.isSelected()) {
        Wynik_rownania_miejsce_zapisu.setText(oblicz_rownanie.funkcja_kwadratowa_obliczanie(Parametr_A_rownania.getText(), Parametr_B_rownania.getText(), Parametr_C_rownania.getText()));
    } else {
        Wynik_rownania_miejsce_zapisu.setText(oblicz_rownanie.funkcja_liniowa_obliczanie(Parametr_A_rownania.getText(), Parametr_B_rownania.getText()));
    }
    rysowanie_na_panelu.Rysuj_uklad(Panel_do_rysowania_funkcji.getHeight(), Panel_do_rysowania_funkcji.getWidth(), getGraphics());
}
```

Now, axes are drawing but not on panel:

[image]

The panel is yellow. Can I set focus on panel or something like this, to draw on panel?

Comment: Sorry for use polish language to calling components :D

Comment: I'd recommend to get used to English names (At least, you did not call it `rysówanie` or so - variables with letters that you can't type on your keyboard can really be blöd ;-)). However, the yellow panel does not seem to be part of the code that you provided. Usually, you just paint things in the overridden `paintCompnent` method of the (yellow) panel.

Comment: @Marco13 Ya i should get used to English names, in future i will try to use it :D Thanks for response and suggested correct solution. Thanks for help.